# Create and fill a dynamic array within function C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

I need to scan `n` numbers and then fill an array with the following scanned `n` numbers. I have to use both `n` and array inputs in a function as well as to use dynamic memory.

```
void input(int* buff, int* n);

int main() {
    int* data = NULL;
    int n;
    input(data, &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void input(int* buff, int *n) {
    if (scanf("%d", n) == 1 && getchar() == '\n') {
        if (*n <= 0) {
            error = 1;
        }
    }

    if (error == 0) {
        buff = (int*)calloc(*n, sizeof(int));
        if (buff == NULL) {
            error = 1;
        }
    }


 if (error == 0) {
        int count = 0;
        int p;
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            if (1 == scanf("%d", &p)) {
                if (count < *n) {
                    *(buff + count) = p;
                    count++;
                }
            }
       }

for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", *(buff + i));
    }
}
```

I didn't insert all the logic of my program in the first `for` since it doesn't really mater.
The last `for` prints proper elements however I have a warning about an empty pointer.

When I return to the `main` and trying to print I've got an error about read access prohibition.
Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` in `main` isn't changed when you change `buff` inside `input`. In other words - `data` will still be NULL when the `input` function returns.

It's just like the `n`... For `n` you correctly pass a pointer to `n` and you need to do exactly the same for `data`.

Like:

```
void input(int** buff, int *n) {
              ^^
           // Notice the two *, i.e. pointer-to-pointer
    ....
    *buff = calloc(....
    ....
```

and call it like

```
input(&data, &n);
```

Comment: And if i need to assign a scanned value to a ```buff``` inside this function, should I use that?
```*buff[count] = p```

Comment: @Arzental In your current code (after the change I suggested), you replace all `buff` with `(*buff)`

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

I've found ```a[2] == *(a + 2) == *(2 + a) == 2[a]```

So in my case it is ```*(*buff + count) == *buff[count]```  ? However right part doesn't work. Unlike your correction (left).

Comment: @Arzental Check C operator precedence... Ask yourself: Is `*buff[count]` the same as `*(buff[count])` or the same as `(*buff)[count]`. That's important.... In other words... when I told you to replace `buff` with `(*buff)` there was a reason for `(....)`

Comment: @Arzental BTW: Have you considered what happens in the scan for `n` fails.

Comment: Scan for ```n``` numbers will stop after the first fail, won't it? ```if (error)``` statement takes care of it.
And in the ```main``` I have a detection for in as well (not in the shown part).

Comment: @Arzental If scan for `n` fails... what happens when you do: `for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", *(buff + i));
    }`

Comment: Ah, I understood what are you talking about. Is is all ok, it was just for testing, I've already deleted this.

Comment: @Arzental I strongly recommend: `int n;` --> `int n = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to allocate one single dynamic array in your function you can just return a pointer to it:

```
int *input(int *buf, int *n);
...
    data = input(data, &n);
...
int *input(int* buff, int *n) {
    ...
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: If `input` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, there is no need for `buff` as a function parameter.

Comment: @4386427: You are right, except that is allows to use an existing (allocated) array or increase it when required with realloc. But I should have said it in my answer. A bit too lazy today...